# how to Update/Add list items via New-WebServiceProxy in powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-services

Over View:

I’m trying to automate updates to a SharePoint list using PowerShell via the Web service object.
 
The end goal is to remove items all from the list, then import new data via a csv file.

Task 1, get items from a SharePoint list - done

Task 2 update/Add items in a share point List - pending
 < Need help with this part, I'm  receiving an error.... See Below! >

Task 3, Remove all items in the list. - Pending

Not Started

**Task 1**

Powershell Code:

```
$listName = "DemoList"
$uri = "http://companyweb/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
$xmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")
$viewFields = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields")
$queryOptions = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")
$rowLimit = "0"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -UseDefaultCredential -uri $uri
$list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "" , $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")
### testing - confirm row count 
$list.data.row.count
##### Select all data
$list.data.row | Select *  | Format-table
```

**Task 2**  [Source Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/06/24/using-new-webserviceproxy-to-get-modify-and-add-items-to-a-list-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx)

```
Powershell Code:
# Get name attribute values (guids) for list and view            
$ndlistview = $service.getlistandview($listname, "")            
$strlistid = $ndlistview.childnodes.item(0).name            
$strviewid = $ndlistview.childnodes.item(1).name            

# Create an xmldocument object and construct a batch element and its     attributes.             
$xmldoc = new-object system.xml.xmldocument             

# note that an empty viewname parameter causes the method to use the default view               
$batchelement = $xmldoc.createelement("batch")            
$batchelement.setattribute("onerror", "continue")            
$batchelement.setattribute("listversion", "1")            
$batchelement.setattribute("viewname", $strviewid)              
# Specify methods for the batch post using caml. to update or delete, specify the id of the     #item, and to update or add, specify the value to place in the specified     column            
$id = 1            
$xml = ""            
# The row to be modified            
$rowId = $list.data.row.ows_id            
# New field value            
$newsport ="soccer"               
$xml += "<method id='$id' cmd='Update'>" +            
        "<field name='ID'>$rowId</field>" +            
        "<field name='Sport'>$newsport</field>" +            
        "</method>"                  
# Set the xml content                    
$batchelement.innerxml = $xml            
$ndreturn = $null             
try {            
    $ndreturn = $service.updatelistitems($listname, $batchelement)             
}            
catch {             
    write-error $_ -erroraction:'stop'            
}
```

## Error :  Update failed

Exception calling "UpdateListItems" with "2" argument(s): "Exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."
At line:98 char:41

Task 3 
Pending

Answer (score 3):

**Task 2**

Replace this line

```
$batchelement = $xmldoc.createelement("batch")
```

by this

```
$batchelement = $xmldoc.createelement("Batch")
```

Problem is your passing wrong parameter to method in return its not taking it in.

**Task 3**

```
try
{ 

System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");

elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1"); 

string strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>" +
"<Field Name='ID'>" + "4" + "</Field></Method>";

elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
ListReference.UpdateListItems("List Name", elBatch); 


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Response.Write(ex.Message);

}
}
```

all you have to do is create a different batch statement and pass it to updatelistitem method, for more explanation check this [link](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2011/06/delete-list-item-using-web-service.html) out

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yaron, 

I can't believe i missed the (B)

This helps out Big Time!

Thanks you!!!

Comment: @SharePointer Unfortunately Mike hasn't been seen since 2012, so I upvoted your helpful answer.